# A stable reference for the following theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request

I'm writing a paper which refers to the following theorem

> Given an $(n, q)-$graph $G$ with $(n, \bar{q}
> )$ complement $\bar{G}$,

> $$k_3(G)+k_3(\bar{G})=\binom{n}{3}-(n-2)q+\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{\deg v_i}{2},$$

> where $n, q$ are the number of vertices and edges of a graph, $k_3(G)$ denotes the number of triangles in graph $G$, and $\deg v_i$ is the degree sequence of $G$.

This theorem can be found in the online [lecture notes](http://www2.fiu.edu/%7Eramsamuj/graphtheory/chap10.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170708231735/http://www2.fiu.edu/%7Eramsamuj/graphtheory/chap10.pdf)) as Theorem 10.1.5, but it'd be better if there's a more stable reference like a published textbook or paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the references that appear immediately above the statement of the theorem in those lecture notes?

There are three: a paper by Lovász in Hungarian, a paper by Moon and Moser that I couldn't find on Google Scholar, and finally [Goodman's 1959 paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2310464) which has this exact result as its Lemma 1:

> **Lemma 1.** For any configuration of $N$ points and $L$ lines, $$E+F = \frac{N(N-1)(N-2)}{6} - (N-2)L + \sum_{j=2}^L \frac{j(j-1)}{2} p_j.$$

(The language of "points" and "lines" is slightly outdated, but what do you expect: it's a 1959 paper.)

Comment: (It didn't appear to bother Goodman that in the sum going from $j=2$ to $j=L$, the terms for $j \ge N$ (which is often most of them) are all going to be $0$.)

Comment: Ah, that's silly of me. Thanks!